# Can't access infopath form on Sharepoint after being given full administrator access to the Sharepoint site. How can I fix this?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I can't access the form fully - I get the error "You do not have permissions to access this form. Contact your PMO". But I have been given full admin access to the sharepoint lists and the whole site.

What could be causing this? Any fixes?

Comment: By full admin access, do you mean the Full Control permission, or were you actually added as a site collection administrator?

Comment: I apologize, I meant the full control permission. However, I do have access to all my department's resources in the site. I work for a big company, so it's a huge site.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your issue is inheritance related.  I would start with looking at the list's permissions and see if it has been broken from the parent site.  If so, then you will need to add Full Control permissions explicitly to this list.